# MongoDB Web API filter syntax for Regex... how is it done?

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb

I have a web connection to our internal MongoDB, I can see the collections I want.
But I want to filter the results based on the text containing a substring...

None of these work:

```
http://mongodb.edu/data/CollectionName/?filter_fieldName={$regex:SomeContainedText}
http://mongodb.edu/data/CollectionName/?filter_fieldName={"$regex":"SomeContainedText"}
http://mongodb.edu/data/CollectionName/?filter_fieldName={"$regex":SomeContainedText}
http://mongodb.edu/data/CollectionName/?filter_fieldName={/SomeContainedText/}
http://mongodb.edu/data/CollectionName/?filter_fieldName={"/SomeContainedText/"}
http://mongodb.edu/data/CollectionName/?filter_fieldName="/SomeContainedText/"
```

Any sugestions on how to find partial text of some fieldname using Web Api interface?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I'm asking as MONGO Web access is there out of the box, I already know how to filter exact keys, and sort but I don't know how to do partial text finds.  To correct your assumptions 1) It's not my API for one thing. 2) I only am trying the regex flag by mongo documents say it's a valid keyword  3) As shown above in the filter syntax there already is a "well formed" syntax for fieldname and value.  4) I agree you aren't sure of what I'm asking but it's pretty clear in the post.  Finally I already have a Mongo client, please refrain from other comments.

Comment: It may be "out of the box" but it really is deliberately "tucked away down the bottom of the box" and hopefully under a pair of old dirty sneakers to keep people away. It really is just a basic interface that was intended for just getting things like collection counts and general admin tasks rather than trying to build anything concrete on it. It is in fact "turned off" by default and natuarally poses a security risk since there is no authentication at all. If you cannot connect a client directly, then ask the nice people to something a bit more supportive to query with. key=value is all.